# Windows Exlorer is slow to load becaue of mapped VPN drive

Tags: vpn, windows-11, mapped-drive

I have a mapped share drive that i connected to occasionally via VPN. Since installing this new mapped share drive, whenever i open my windows explorer, it takes at least 1 minute before i can select anything. The explorer window simply freezes up.

I realize this is because windows attempts to connect to the VPN share drive, but waits incredibly long before timing out.

The computer is barely usable like this. **How can I prevent it from freezing up?**

Reading up on the internet, I have attempted to get it to work by deleting all shortcuts in the navigation pane, but that has not helped.

Comment: Try in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters` to create a REG_DWORD item named `autodisconnect` with the value `0` and reboot.

Comment: Also you can have a Mapped Drive disconnect batch file and add that to Group Policy logoff scripts. Either approach.

Comment: Is mapping the drive particularly important for your workflow? As in, does it have to have a drive letter? I ask because it might be simpler using the UNC path to your shared drive instead (i.e \\drive\share), and then place a shortcut for this area on your desktop.

Comment: @Mastaxx Unfortunately it does have an impact on my workflow. I specifically require it in order to provide support for an MS Access application, which has the backend linked to another file. Maintaining it with a letter drive is way easier than a UNC path. So I do want to find a solution that allows me to keep the mapped letter drive.

Comment: @John That sounds like an interesting solution. How would I go about doing that. Implementing group policy is something i have not done before.

Comment: @harrymc I'll need to figure out how to add that to the registry, but I assume this solution would essentially tell windows not to check for a connection when booting. Am I right about that?

Comment: It might shorten the connection time to a few seconds, if it works.

Comment: I posted a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

A well used solution to this issue that uses standard, readily available Windows Tools is to use Gpedit.msc (Local Group Policy) to run a Logoff script. I use this on my computers to disconnect mapped drives when logging off or shutting down.

Open Gpedit.msc (Admin Tools) and navigate to User Configuration, Windows Settings, Scripts.

Make a logoff script for the drive in question, save it in (say) disconnect folders.bat

Open the Logoff script and put in the batch file.  Save and test.

The screenshot assumes Disconnect Folders.bat is on the Desktop.  Use the full path if you have the batch file somewhere else.

Tested here and works.

[image: Windows logoff script]